# NOT NULL constraint failed Django CreateView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

I would like to accomplish two goals on this project. First, I would like to save the logged-in user as the reviewer. Second, I want to pass the lawyer value from the foreignkey into the review form. (This way, the user can review click on a review link on the lawyer's detail page and review that lawyer and no one else.)

I keep getting on the first goal, with this error.

error

```
IntegrityError at /lawyers/karlyn-rosemarie-hylton/review/
NOT NULL constraint failed: lawyers_review.reviewer_id
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

The second goal seems to be very related to the first goal. I am not getting any errors for it. But I want to make sure that I am doing it right. However, I won't be able to tell until I get passed the first error.

Any help getting unstuck is much appreciated.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Lawyer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55,
                            default='')
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/lawyers/pictures', 
                                default='')
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def average_rating(self):
        all_ratings = map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all())
        return np.mean(all_ratings)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = (slugify(self.name))
        super(Lawyer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lawyers:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 


class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    lawyer = models.ForeignKey(Lawyer, 
                                null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=55,
                                default='')
    comment = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lawyer.name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import (CreateView,
                                    DetailView,
                                    ListView)


from django.contrib.auth.models import User


from .models import Lawyer, Review


class AddLawyerView(CreateView):
    model = Lawyer 
    fields = ['name', 'picture']

    def post_valid(self, form):
        lawyer = form.save(Commit=False)
        lawyer.picture = form.cleaned_data['picture']
        return super(AddLawyerView, self).form_valid(form)


class LawyerDetail(DetailView):
    model = Lawyer 


class LawyerList(ListView):
    model = Lawyer 


class AddReviewView(CreateView):
    model = Review 
    fields = ['rating', 'title', 'comment']

    def post_valid(self, form):
        review = form.save(Commit=False)
        review.lawyer = get_object_or_404(Lawyer, 
                                            slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        review.reviewer = User.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return super(AddReview, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url


from .views import (AddLawyerView, 
                    LawyerDetail,
                    LawyerList,
                    AddReviewView)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add-lawyer',
        AddLawyerView.as_view(),
        name = 'add-lawyer'),


    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        LawyerDetail.as_view(),
        name = 'detail'),


    url(r'^$',
        LawyerList.as_view(),
        name = 'list'),


    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/review/$',
        AddReviewView.as_view(),
        name = 'add-review'),
]
```

Using the feedback from @Alasdair and @Sachin Kukreja , I went back and made some correction. I changed "Commit" to "commit" and "post_valid" to "form_valid". I also made one minor tweak to simplify the view. The corrected and working AddReviewView is below. The one with mistakes is above.

Thank you all!

Working View:

```
class AddReviewView(CreateView):
    model = Review 
    fields = ['rating', 'title', 'comment']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        review = form.save(commit=False)
        review.lawyer = get_object_or_404(Lawyer, 
                                            slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        review.reviewer = self.request.user
        return super(AddReviewView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace ?

Comment: Note it should be `commit=False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo there, you are overriding `form_valid` but you have written `post_valid`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    review = form.save(Commit=False)
    review.lawyer = get_object_or_404(Lawyer, 
                                        slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
    review.reviewer = User.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

    # save and return HttpResponse
    review.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

But, the `super` call will still call the parent class' `form_valid` which will still raise the error. I think you can save the review in this overriden method and return what the base class returns i.e. `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`

Ref: [form_valid in FormMixin class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L55), [form_valid in ModelFormMixin class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L123)